# Run another application from within my app, but continue executing when that app has closed?

Tags: android, android-intent, wait, background-foreground

Okay so, I have a program (prog1) that opens another program through an `intent` (prog2).  My goal is to have prog1 not do anything while prog2 is in the foreground.  When prog2 exits the foreground, have prog1 continue executing.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
        LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("prog2");     
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    }}, 3000);  // 3 seconds
```

But I don't know where to go from here.

Is this at all possible?  Can anyone provide guidance as to where to go from here?

Comment: A wild guess but try startActivityForResult()

Comment: Have you tried overriding onpause and onresume? Pause the process when the 2nd app has opened and resume when closed.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to guarantee this to work. startActivityForResult() will only return a result if the activity you call it from is still accessible. If you start a new application this will send your current activity into the background where it is subject to garbage collection, if it gets gc'ed there is no way to receive the result. The way to avoid that would be to link it somehow to the application you call (like with service binding). If, by chance, the called application sends out a system broadcast on close you could register a receiver in the manifest that listens for it.

Comment: Yeah, startActivityForResult() doesn't work, as the application does not return a result...  Is there a way to monitor for broadcasts?